# Data Sorting and filtering (From an Excel File)

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, filtering

Please refer to the Data Tables Below...

[Input table]

| Input Table |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TABLE: Joint Reactions |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Joint | LC | F1 | F2 | F3 | M1 | M2 | M3 |
| Text | Text | KN | KN | KN | KN-m | KN-m | KN-m |
| 1 | SF-DL | 5.97 | 4.517 | 169.179 | -2.167 | 3.249 | -0.0042 |
| 1 | OTH-DL | 1.268 | 0.667 | 20.592 | -0.3083 | 0.7476 | 0.0253 |
| 1 | LL | 1.488 | 1.3 | 16.341 | -0.5738 | 0.7014 | -0.0307 |
| 3 | SF-DL | 5.97 | -4.517 | 169.179 | 2.167 | 3.249 | 0.0042 |
| 3 | OTH-DL | 1.268 | -0.667 | 20.592 | 0.3083 | 0.7476 | -0.0253 |
| 3 | LL | 1.488 | -1.3 | 16.341 | 0.5738 | 0.7014 | 0.0307 |
| 5 | SF-DL | 1.024 | 6.039 | 201.94 | -2.1923 | 0.7081 | 0.0165 |
| 5 | OTH-DL | 0.373 | 0.669 | 31.867 | -0.3234 | 0.2567 | 0.0234 |
| 5 | LL | 0.2 | 7.297 | 28.116 | -2.5342 | 0.1201 | -0.021 |
| 7 | SF-DL | 1.024 | -6.039 | 201.94 | 2.1923 | 0.7081 | -0.0165 |
| 7 | OTH-DL | 0.373 | -0.669 | 31.867 | 0.3234 | 0.2567 | -0.0234 |
| 7 | LL | 0.2 | -7.297 | 28.116 | 2.5342 | 0.1201 | 0.021 |

[output table in excel]

| Output Table formulae results |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TABLE: Joint Reactions |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Joint | LC | F1 | F2 | F3 | M1 | M2 | M3 |
| Text | Text | KN | KN | KN | KN-m | KN-m | KN-m |
| 1 | SF-DL | 5.97 | 4.517 | 169.179 | -2.167 | 3.249 | -0.0042 |
| 3 | SF-DL | 5.97 | -4.517 | 169.179 | 2.167 | 3.249 | 0.0042 |
| 5 | SF-DL | 1.024 | 6.039 | 201.94 | -2.1923 | 0.7081 | 0.0165 |
| 7 | SF-DL | 1.024 | -6.039 | 201.94 | 2.1923 | 0.7081 | -0.0165 |
| 1 | OTH-DL | 1.268 | 0.667 | 20.592 | -0.3083 | 0.7476 | 0.0253 |
| 3 | OTH-DL | 1.268 | -0.667 | 20.592 | 0.3083 | 0.7476 | -0.0253 |
| 5 | OTH-DL | 0.373 | 0.669 | 31.867 | -0.3234 | 0.2567 | 0.0234 |
| 7 | OTH-DL | 0.373 | -0.669 | 31.867 | 0.3234 | 0.2567 | -0.0234 |
| 1 | LL | 1.488 | 1.3 | 16.341 | -0.5738 | 0.7014 | -0.0307 |
| 3 | LL | 1.488 | -1.3 | 16.341 | 0.5738 | 0.7014 | 0.0307 |
| 5 | LL | 0.2 | 7.297 | 28.116 | -2.5342 | 0.1201 | -0.021 |
| 7 | LL | 0.2 | -7.297 | 28.116 | 2.5342 | 0.1201 | 0.021 |

I want to sort and filter The Input Table and put the data in output table format.

I have an excel sheet prepared by my friend....He has done Sorting and Filtering using some formulae and functions....refer output table in excel.

I am new to python...and want to do the same thing in python...

1. extracting data from excel and saving a data frame in python
2. filtering and sorting as per output table in python
3. exporting the output table to excel.

Please help me in this regard.

I am unable to come up with a solution since I am new to python

Comment: I have reduced the table and updated post as per request....but still  no response......I think people are more interested in finding mistakes than solving the questions....

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342788/997587)!

Comment: Dear @starball Please note that if your are unable to understand the issues.....and unable to answer a question....then please do not comment.....as......silence is golden.....thanks